# Logic Pro X - How do I enter a triplet rest in the score editor?

Tags: notation, logic-pro, tuplet, rests

I'm trying to enter the following into Logic Pro X:

[image: Triplet marking over a crotchet rest and two crotchets. Another triplet marking over three crotchets.]

but I don't know how to enter the rest as a triplet.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Display Mode > Custom

[image: Display Mode > Custom]

---

Change 'Division' to /12

[image: 'Division' to /12]

---

Draw notes onto the Piano Roll in the following manner (Each division is /12th and not /16th or /32nd)
[image: piano roll]

...and that's it!
[image: solution]

Answer (score 0):

A triplet is 3 notes in the time of two. In your example there are 3 quarter notes in the time of two quarter notes. SO if you want to enter a rest to equal the quarter note triplet, enter a minim rest or two quarter note rests WITHOUT using the triplet notation.